# How to enter to chat room to discuss topicality on the site?

Tags: support, chat

I'm struggling with few warnings in my code. I would like to discuss that in chat room, if there was anybody available with knowledge and experience related to my issue.

How can I enter in chat room?

Comment: I think a rep of 20 is required

Comment: You need some minimum reputation points to enter chat rooms here. Sorry. Why don't you just ask your question here? That way you will fast receive reputation points too !

Comment: i have completed questions limitations. My questions are not posting.

Comment: Learn how site [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) system works

Comment: @arkascha you don't gain or lose rep on Meta

Answer (score 6):

The first requirement to join a chat is to gain at least 20 reputation. Before that you may view the chat, but you can't write anything. Reputation is earned by asking good on topic questions or answering questions.

If there is no chat on your topic you may create your own room, but this requires you to have at least 100 rep to do so. [For more information on  privileges, read here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

### How to successfully join in on a chat

Most rooms have rules. This is a general thing you should always look for in any chat no matter where on the internet you are. On StackOverflow these rules are mostly found in the room description. Read them before posting.

#### General rules of the chat

Do nots:

- Don't ask to ask, if anyone specific is there or for expertise in the
  area of your question.
- StackOverflow is not your personal
  help-center. Noone is obliged to help you, it's something we do out
  of the kindness of our hearts so be polite and accept if no-one
  might want to answer your question.
- Ask more than once. People generally back-trace the chat transcript so there's no need for you to spam your question over and over.
- Nag about your question. Asking repeatedly for help will be contra-productive. If someone wants to answer they will.
- Do not ping people needlessly. Unless you're answering/commenting on something they said, don't ping them. People find this annoying.
- Beg for upvotes.

  - Post code bigger than one line in the chat.

Do:

- Just ask your question if you have one. If someone can or want to answer they will eventually.
- Initiate friendly conversations. Saying hi or joining in on the topic is welcome. Initiating your own topis is fine.
- Use the sandbox chat to test text formats or other chat-related things.
- Keep a friendly tone. Not all chats are PG 13 but get to know the people in the chat before you get **too** friendly with them. We do have a lot of minors after all.
- Use a service like http://pastebin.com to post code.
- Link to your StackOverflow question if you've made one.

Comment: A lot of these "general rules" are very localized. General guidelines are already covered on [the official FAQ](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq). Some rooms, for instance, doesn't care about code dumps nor being friendly *cough*.

Comment: They are the general rules in all the SO chats I've ever used. Noone's gonna be upset with you following them, but the other way around can cause friction in a lot of chats. I didn't link to the FAQ since answers should contain the answers, not links to the answer. :p

Answer (score -3):

Use this link:

[**LINK**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

If you have enough reputation then you can use this feature. I think 20 reputation  needed.